# Does conditional expectation exist if marginal expectation exists?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given two random variables $X,Y$ on the same probability space, given that $E[Y]$ exists, does $E[Y|X=x]$ exist for all $x$ such that $f_X(x)>0$?

My argument : no it does not. If $E[Y|X=x]$ is a Dirac delta pulse at $x=x_0$ with $0<f_X(x_0) < + \infty$ then

$$E[Y] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{} E[Y|X=x]f_X(x) dx = f_X(x_0) < +\infty$$

Thus $E[Y]$ exists but $E[Y|X]$ does not.

Is my argument correct? If not how do I go about correcting it?

Definition of Dirac delta pulse taken from : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Comment: I don't understand the argumentation you use, but your conclusion is wrong. The reason is that $E[Y\mid X] $ exists as long as $E[|Y|] <\infty$.

Comment: Could you please point out which part of my argument is unclear? Could you give some hint on how to prove your proposition? That would probably get me clear on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Added definition of Dirac delta pulse to the question in case that was the point of confusion.

Comment: If $Z$ is a $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable, then $Z = g(X)$ for some Borel measurable function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $E[Y\mid X=x]$ is the function $g$ obtained by applying this result to $E[Y\mid X]$, which is a $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable. In particular, it makes no sense of saying that $E[Y \mid X=x]$ is a Dirac mass.